# button is not disabling in internet explorer 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have defined the button as

```
  <input type="button" id="disable" disabled="disabled" value="Upload" />
```

But the button is not looking like disabled in chrome, firefox and safari. and in ie it is even clicking.

Comment: tried `disabled="true"`? If it's not clickable - it's probably disabled.

Comment: well different browser has their own css for displaying default css for each DOM that does not mean its not working.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1894957.aspx

Comment: Can't repeat the problem using any browser. Could you add an example using JSfiddle? [This](http://jsfiddle.net/tZtHN/1/) would seem to work on Chrome, Safari and IE10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use disabled attribute without argument.

```
<button disabled></button>
<input type="button" disabled value="input"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4GAWv/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write disabled="disabled". 
use this code.

```
<input type="button" id="disabled" value="upload" disabled />
```